# how to manage array React js set state for similar input fields with same label

Tags: reactjs

[Frontend view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YECYP.png)

This is my table where there will be multiple table rows and each table data will have input fields in it.
This is my row component having input fields in  tags:

```
<tr>
  <td><div className="content_box"><input onChange={handleChange}/></div></td>
  <td><div className="content_box"><input /></div></td>
  <td><div className="content_box"><input /></div></td>
  <td><div className="content_box perage"><input /></div></td>
  <td><div className="content_box"><input type="file" className="bit_set" name="document" id="upload-doc" /></div></td>
  <td><div className="del_add"><span ><a onClick={()=>{setRowsCount(rowsCount+1)}}>+</a></span> {rowsCount !==1 ? <span onClick={()=>setRowsCount(rowsCount-1)} className="del_col_change"><a>-</a></span>:null}</div></td>
</tr>
```

and this is my parent Component:

```
import TableRow from './TableRow';
import './PegramNoyaceStep2.css'
function PegramNoyaceAgencyStep2() {
  const [previousrows,setPreviousRows] = useState(1)
  const [previousCarriers,setPreviousCarriers] = useState([])
  const [previousTotalPremium,setPreviousTotalPremium] = useState([])
  const [previousTotalCommission,setPreviousTotalCommission] = useState([])
  const [previousLossRatio,setPreviousLossRatio] = useState([])
  const [previousCommissionStatement,setPreviousCommissionStatement] = useState([])
  var foo = [...Array(previousrows).keys()]
  const [currentrows,setCurrentRows] = useState(1)
  const [currentCarriers,setCurrentCarriers] = useState([])
  const [currentTotalPremium,setCurrentTotalPremium] = useState([])
  const [currentTotalCommission,setCurrentTotalCommission] = useState([])
  const [currentLossRatio,setCurrentLossRatio] = useState([])
  const [currentCommissionStatement,setCurrentCommissionStatement]=useState([])                                                                                                                                                                        
  var foobar = [...Array(currentrows).keys()]
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
            
            console.log('hello')
            const step2params = {
              prevYear:{
                carriers:previousCarriers
              },
              currYear:{
                carriers:currentCarriers
              }
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(step2params))
  }
  return (
    <div className="PegramNoyaceAgencyStep2">

<section class="two_s">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="dash_heading">The peagram-Noyace Agency</div>
<div class="dash_heading_two">Dashboard</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<section class="three_s">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="top_step">
<h2>Step 2</h2>
<p>Career, Premium, & Commissions</p>

</div>

    
<div class="table_blocks_overall">
<h3>Previous Year</h3>
<div class="full_table">

  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        
        <th scope="col">Carieer Represented</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Premium</th>
        <th>Total Commission</th>
        <th scope="col">Loss Ratio</th>
        <th>Commission Statement</th>
       
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {foo.map((k)=><TableRow pcar={previousCarriers} spcar={setPreviousCarriers} ptp={previousTotalPremium} sptp={setPreviousTotalPremium} ptc={previousTotalCommission} sptc={setPreviousTotalCommission} plr={previousLossRatio} splr={setPreviousLossRatio} pcs={previousCommissionStatement} spcs={setPreviousCommissionStatement} rowsCount={previousrows} setRowsCount={setPreviousRows} key={k.index} />)}
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>



<div class="table_blocks_overall">
  <h3>Current Year</h3>
  <div class="full_table table-responsive">
  
    <table class="table  ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          
          <th scope="col">Carieer Represented</th>
          <th scope="col">Total Premium</th>
          <th>Total Commission</th>
          <th scope="col">Loss Ratio</th>
          <th>Commission Statement</th>
         
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {foobar.map((k)=><TableRow pcar={currentCarriers} spcar={setCurrentCarriers} ptp={currentTotalPremium} sptp={setCurrentTotalPremium} ptc={currentTotalCommission} sptc={setCurrentTotalCommission} plr={currentLossRatio} splr={setCurrentLossRatio} pcs={currentCommissionStatement} spcs={setCurrentCommissionStatement} rowsCount={currentrows} setRowsCount={setCurrentRows} key={k.index} />)}
   
  
  
     
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button onClick={(e)=>submitHandler(e)}></button>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>

</div>
);
}
```

Now i want to store all the input data in array:

```
const [previousCarriers,setPreviousCarriers] = useState([])
const [previousTotalPremium,setPreviousTotalPremium] = useState([])
const [previousTotalCommission,setPreviousTotalCommission] = useState([])
const [previousLossRatio,setPreviousLossRatio] = useState([])
const [previousCommissionStatement,setPreviousCommissionStatement] = useState([])
const [currentCarriers,setCurrentCarriers] = useState([])
const [currentTotalPremium,setCurrentTotalPremium] = useState([])
const [currentTotalCommission,setCurrentTotalCommission] = useState([])
const [currentLossRatio,setCurrentLossRatio] = useState([])
const [currentCommissionStatement,setCurrentCommissionStatement] = useState([])
```

like this:
Now the main problem i am facing with this approach is that suppose i am on first row of carrier represented i have added input text foo and later on i have gone to second row of carrier represented and added field bar but after some time i want to edit first row again by adding foo bar in it then my carrier state looks like this `['foo','bar','foobar']` instead of `['foobar,'bar']`

Comment: Would it not be easier to have a state variable like `rows` that stores an array of objects? Each object would represent a row with keys for values like `carrier`, `premium` etc.

Comment: yes it would be but i don't know how it could be acheived